# How to make query string values case insensitive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24699643/6676148) I get to know about the case sensitivity of the query string **keys**. But my query is regarding the case sensitivity the query string **value**. Is it possible to make the query string values case insensitive? 
Can it be possible to get same result when i hit the below two urls?

```
http://eventabc.com/test/#/?layout=1&name=WCC 

and

http://eventabc.com/test/#/?layout=1&name=wcc
```

If there is any way please give me some solution in angularjs.

Comment: One solution is to query out the value  and convert it either into uppercase or lowercase.so regardless of value in url you get same result

Comment: @SereneAbrahamMathew .My question is actually, how to get same result from both the urls?

Comment: I mean like this `request.querystring("name").toUpperCase()`      This always yields same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using IIS express, Whenever you provide uppercase in query string the URL is automatically converted to lower case. Because this is happened in IIS express.

> So you need to move  hosted project to local IIS instead of IIS express, and the automatic lowercase redirect is gone

Please find this discussion: [Angular 2 Route Param automatically converting to lowercase on localhost but remains capitalized on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231591/angular-2-route-param-automatically-converting-to-lowercase-on-localhost-but-rem)

If you want to know the value is uppercase or lowercase, then please try this below way

```
if (value== value.toLowerCase())
{
  // The character is lowercase
}
else
{
  // The character is uppercase
}
```

Comment: This concept help me and i resolved my issue.Thanks. I just compared value.toLowerCase() with anotherValue.toLowercase() .